Klaviyo API Retirement on June 30th
I got an email that says we will be affected by the API retiring in a week. We are running Magento 2 version 2.4.5 and Klaviyo version 3.0.11. If this chart is correct, then we need to upgrade to at least plugin version 4.1.0.
I spoke with our Klaviyo manager and they mentioned that Magento was making changes to deal with this and that no development action is required. Can anyone verify this?

I believe you have to upgrade the extension to latest version as the mentioned on site https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005254348#h_01HNZMK310HQPFJWZ2NB1C6NSC , Attaching screenshot for reference
https://prnt.sc/vorc34vDz8mf
